# contextual filter in Drupal 7 sql error

Tags: drupal, view

I have a view with is a page layout.  The path is set to /users/%/profiles 
I want to feed it a user name and filter the content where author name = fileter.
I created a contextual filter of User: Authentication name , I really want the user name of the author of the content. I believe this is correct.

The rest of the view is working. If I remove the contextual filter I get all items of the content type I am looking for.

when I try to browse /users/jjones/profiles I get the same error as below on the auto preview.

When I try to use the auto preview I get an sql error  near \'= \'jjones\')

I can;t get my hands on the full sql since it is very deep in the drupal core (I hate that).

Drupal 7.8
Views module 7.x-3.0-rc1

Comment: Did you enable Contextual module, it's core module of drupal.

Comment: Yes it's enabled and permissions have been granted to authenticated users.  I wish I knew if this is a drupal bug or due to my configuration.